# NUnit custom Timeout Attribute

Tags: c#, testing, attributes, nunit

I am trying to implement my own version of the Timeout attribute because I need to run TearDown if the set test time expires
However, I could not figure out how to get from Context or Command what is being executed-the test method or SetUp (I also wanted to ignore its execution)
Are there any possibilities to implement a custom version of Timeout that would only take into account the test itself without the SetUp and TearDown methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to create an attribute that works as you describe. However, it can't be "a new version of the TimeoutAttribute" since that attribute aleady exists within NUnit. It will have to be a new attribute written in a different way.

The current `TimeoutAttribute` is one of the older attribute implementations in NUnit. It actually does very little itself. Instead, it merely leaves behind information as a property of the test object, which is later acted upon internally by NUnit. Most attributes have by now been converted to a different approach, wherein the attribute itself adds code to the command structure for the test - I'll call this an "active attribute" for easy reference.

The underlying reason that `TimeoutAttribute` still uses an older style (call it "passive" if you like) is that it actually does two quite different things:

1. When it appears on a method, it sets the timeout for that method.
2. When it appears on a class or assembly, it sets the default timeout, which is used when a method has no timeout set.

I believe that this dual usage was an unfortunate design error. (I can say that since it was my error.) It limits the ability to do what you would like to do. However, by ignoring the existing attribute completely, you can create one yourself. The coding is non-trivial but here's what I suggest:

1. Your attribute should implement the `IWrapTestMethod` interface. NUnit will call it's `Wrap` method at the appropriate time.
2. The `Wrap` method will create an object derived from `TestCommand`, which runs the test method by calling the base command `Execute` on a separate thread and waits for that thread to finish. It should kill the thread if it doesn't finish within the allowed time.

This is **not** a simple custom attribute to write. You will have to create quite a lot of code within the attribute to do this. In fact, you will be duplicating a large amount of what is already found in NUnit itself. For example, you will need to deal with both synchronous and async test methods and you will need to generate a failing result just as NUnit does.

Because this is so involved, it would probably be better to modify NUnit internally. However, such a modification is likely to be a breaking change, so I don't think it will happen anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to have a custom timeout attribute that does not interrupt me from debugging when a timeout is set.
My working version :

```
/// <summary>
/// Applies a timeout in milliseconds to a test. 
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class MyTimeoutAttribute: PropertyAttribute, IWrapTestMethod
{
    private const int InfiniteTimeout = Int32.MaxValue;
    private readonly int _timeout;

    public MyTimeoutAttribute(int timeout)
        : base(timeout)
    {
        //if a debugger is attached => disable timeout by setting an infinite one
        _timeout = Debugger.IsAttached ? InfiniteTimeout : timeout;
    }

    public TestCommand Wrap(TestCommand command)
    {
        return new TimeoutCommand(command, _timeout);
    }
}
```